# Proof of accommodation in Schengen area

Tags: schengen-visas

Can I print my confirmation email sent to me by Booking.com and use it for my  Schengen visa application as proof of hotel accommodation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

[SchengenVisaInfo](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-application-requirements/) addresses this:

> Proof of accommodation. A document that shows where you will be
>   accommodated throughout your stay in Schengen. This can be one of the
>   following:
>
> - A hotel/hostel booking.
> - A rental agreement.
> - A letter of invitation from a host at whose house you will be staying.